# How to run a custom Karate project on VSCode

Tags: karate

I'm writing a test project on IntelliJ with custom Java libraries. Is it possible to run it through VSCode in order to use the debug features of the Karate plugin? If I try to run it I get the following error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven- 
metadata.xml
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml 
(20 kB at 23 kB/s)
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven- 
metadata.xml (14 kB at 15 kB/s)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.954 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-10-27T16:50:14+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix '.options=c' in the current project and in the plugin groups 
[org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local 
(C:\Users\asd\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following 
articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command mvn clean 
test -f "c:\Users\asd\Documents\test-karate\com.testK\com.testK-karate\pom.xml" - 
Dtest=_SyncRunner "-Dkarate.options=c:\Users\asd\Documents\test-karate\com.testK\com.testK- 
karate\src\test\java\test.feature" " 
terminated with exit code: 1.
```

The project is running correctly on IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

From the command it is clear you are using Powershell. Please switch the VS Code "default shell" to `cmd`. You can find instructions here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Karate-Robot-Windows-Install-Guide#install-visual-studio-code

[image]

Comment: Now I'm getting

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project com.testK: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]   

The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe /d /c mvn clean test -f "c:\Users\asd\Documents\test-karate\com.testK\com.testK-karate\pom.xml" -Dtest=_SyncRunner "-Dkarate.options=c:\Users\asd\Documents\test-karate\com.testK\com.testK-karate\pom.xml" " terminated with exit code: 1.`

Comment: If I run debug I get instead:

`Error: could not find or load main class com.intuit.karate.Main
The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe /d /c java -cp karate.jar;karate-robot.jar;. com.intuit.karate.Main -d" terminated with exit code: 1.`

Comment: @Leonardo ok I'm going to give up :) there's a few settings for the plugin you do need to get right. also scan the issues like this one: https://github.com/kirksl/karate-runner/issues/66